# Codeigniter - Combining Get and then Update on same query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am using below code to get records with specified condition, and then to update only the same records.

```
$this->db->where('Parameter1', 'TRUE');
$query = $this->db->get('Messages');

$this->db->where('Parameter1', 'TRUE');
$this->db->set('Parameter1', 'FALSE');
$this->db->update('Messages');
```

This works, but calling two times the same query using where() command seems like wasting of server power. Is it possible to make get() command not reset query or to use the previous record set in the update command?

Comment: add actual code without  `Parameter1` it's hard to understand. And you're doing nothing with `$query` output

Comment: Normally, we get and update in different functions in model. In your code segment, I am not able to find a reason to get same record which you want to update. Can you elaborate the case a little more?

Comment: Yes, the user requests to read new messages adressed to him/her, so the script is reading those new messages from the table that store messages, and then it needs to save to that table information that the message has been "read". Let's say Parameter1 describes, if a message is new (TRUE), or has been already read (FALSE).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is something you really need to worry about taking up too many resources, and you can't really reuse the where clause in the actual sql query. But if you'd like you can refactor to get slightly cleaner code.

```
$unread = array('Parameter1'=>TRUE);
$read = array('Parameter1'=> FALSE);

$query = $this->db->get_where('Messages', $unread); 

$this->db->update('Messages', $read, $unread);
```

**Note:**
In your code your getting **every** element where Parameter1 is set to true, and then changing **every** one of those elements to false. This almost certainly is not desirable, but perhaps it is a problem you take care of somewhere else in your real application.